# checksum md5 for thumbnails linux

Tags: linux, thumbnails, md5sum, video-thumbnails, ffmpegthumbnailer

there is a [standard](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/thumbnail-spec/thumbnail-spec-latest.html) for calculating the checksum of a thumbnail using md5sum, but in some file managers (dolphin, deepin-FM) it is considered in some other way.
For example, for a file whose absolute path is `file:///media/home/file.mkv` nautilus and caja create a thumbnail file named `682433b1f02832783d4cb739d2e705ff.png`, which conforms to the standard,

`echo -n "file:///media/home/file.mkv" | md5sum 682433b1f02832783d4cb739d2e705ff -`

but dolphin create thumbnails named `682433b1f02832783d4cb739d2e705ff.png`, `33a417e81b4f8894d1a23406e827a23b.png` and 4`4feee170f71b4894f399af9f5a8eb33.png`, deepin-FM create thumbnails named `668464f69987d58a1062a34490fc4dec.png`.
Attention to the question, how (preferably a command or a link to the standard) checksums are calculated in the dolphin and deepin-FM file managers?

I tryed any commands ``` md5sum <<< "file:///media/home/file.mkv"``echo "file:///media/home/file.mkv" | md5sum ``` `echo -e "file:///media/home/file.mkv" | md5sum` its not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo -n $(stat -c "file://%n%i" /media/home/file.mkv) | md5sum
```